# Customizing SharePoint AspMenu control

Tags: navigation, branding, custom, inheritance

I'm currently working on a project in which the navigation needs to have some special touches in order to fulfill the clients wishes.

Instead of the casual SharePoint topnavigation dropdown I want to expand, so it might have 2 or more columns in 1 dropdown

TOP LEVEL /
|_ Sub level 1 | Sub level 1 | Sub level 1
|_ Sub level 1 | Sub level 1 | Sub level 1
|_ Sub level 1 | Sub level 1 | Sub level 1

Beside from that I want to be able to control what items is to the left in the top navigation bar and which are to the right.

TOP LEVEL 1 | TOP LEVEL 2 |---------------------| TOP LEVEL 3

So is it possible to inherit the AspMenu control to achieve this or do I have to develop my own control entirely from scratch?

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem?

Comment: Yes. I went online and found a product called Mega Drop Down by the company Archetonomy. It works according to our requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the changes you need are only in UI, you need not write a new menu control. You can have the effect using jquery plugins which work with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags

Comment: Say I have a navigation item called **Departments** with 3 subsites and in its dropdown I want to display the 3 subsites in each their column, and what if 1 or more gets added, how would I categorize them into each their column dynamically without changing the plugin script all the time?